# The tensor product over $R$ or $M$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, tensor-products, tensors, group-cohomology

Here is the Kunneth formula I found for cohomology on the internet here https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Kunneth_formula_for_cohomology:

> [image]

But I am confused about if the tensor product over $R$ or $M$? I am guessing it is over $M, $ can anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: What would a tensor product over a module be?

Comment: @CaptainLama are you saying that a tensor product over  a module should be over the ring of the module?

Comment: I'm saying that as far as I know there is no such thing as a tensor product over a module (but I don't know everything !).

Comment: @CaptainLama ok, thank you!!